# What did this question do to warrant deletion?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, moderation

Not really sure what has happened here, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66821988/692942) has been unceremoniously deleted by a moderator without any reason given as far as I can see. The only reason I know is because my answer was affected.

Does anyone know why this has been deleted?

I've just noticed it says in the timeline via vote, would a moderator give the casting vote?

Comment: Moderators votes are binding. For transparency: that question has passed SOCVR twice: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=66821988&room=90230

Comment: Yes, the first time I was one of the users who flagged it but after some further conversation if seemed it wasn't so I requested to re-open the question. Why does that warranty deletion? It's hard enough to answering decent questions in marginalised tags, but then to them straight up deleted after effort has been put into answer them is really frustrating.

Comment: Only meager can answer that. I'm sure he'll be contacted in the blue room and share his reasoning here. Give it 6 to 8 hours.

Comment: Wow, there's a lot of comments under that. Do you mind briefly explaining what led to your change of mind after originally voting to close?

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Main reason for me was simply, the OP was getting bad advice in the comments and with the question closed I couldn't give an answer to straighten things out (in the end I resorted to a gist).

Comment: Honestly, the amount of *trash* questions we get in the tags I follow but then this gets deleted, I don't get it. There's far worse.

Comment: I mean... your answer basically repeats the answer that you linked to. Am I missing something? Was it only reopened because of comments?

Comment: In this case, I flagged the comment thread for cleanup/migration to chat, and that is probably what got meagar's attention in the first place. Like all moderators, he can and does regularly delete stuff he comes across even when that stuff was not directly flagged, if he deems deletion appropriate. That being said, I don't know why he deleted this question in particular. Based on the comments, it seemed like OP's solution was not covered by the duplicate target's answers, though I do also recall missing that the Q was tagged [tag:html]. I may not have cast a reopen vote if I had realized that.

Comment: That question is a mess. A Stack Snippet for a bunch of VBScript? UPDATE? Latest Update? If you want the question to survive, help the OP out and edit the question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I just haven’t had the time to tidy the question, but didn’t expect the next thing it would be deleted.

Comment: There's only so much you can do to salvage a question; that one had plenty of time to improve.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have to be completely honest on this one: I have *no idea* why I would have deleted it, or any memory of doing so. I don't recognize it at all, and I did not delete it on purpose. I've undeleted it now.

Around the time of deletion yesterday, I was researching a character encoding problem, which is the only way I can think of that I may have come across that question, but I definitely did not delete it intentionally, so apologies for that.

It's possible I fat-fingered this somehow, or maybe had several questions under review open in multiple tabs, and managed to delete the wrong one.

Comment: Perhaps because it exposes actual credentials?  https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66821988/13

Comment: Appreciate the honesty, it did seem weird to me for it to be deleted outright. Thank you.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think I would remember the question, if that was the case. The graphics make it particularly memorable.

Comment: @RobertHarvey correct me if I am wrong, but I thought if credentials were exposed the revisions would have to be redacted. The post itself can't be deleted because 10k users can still see the credentials.